# does pybind11 support 'from <package> import <module>' style import?

Tags: python-3.x, pybind11

how do i do `from <package> import <module>` in pybind11?

I do not want to do `import <package>` and then getattr as below.

```
auto package = pybind11::module::import("package");
auto module =  package.attr("module")
```

Comment: Posted the same at https://gitter.im/pybind/Lobby. got answer `auto module = pybind11::module::import("package.module")`. that works.

Answer (score 0):

To make the C++ code completely equivalent to `from <package> import <module>` at global scope you need to set attribute of the module where you do import:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

    auto package = pybind11::module::import("package");
    auto module =  package.attr("module")
    m.add_object("module", module);
}
```

[pybind11::module::add_object](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/759221f5c56939f59d8f342a41f8e2d2cacbc8cf/include/pybind11/pybind11.h#L868)